# Ruby on Rails: Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I've set up a scaffold for a hypothetical application with a users log in, but run into the following error when I try to create a user using the view

```
undefined method `encrypted_password=' for #<User:0x007fdffb0303a8>
```

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Sergio. But just to elaborate, follow the instructions below since it seems you may be new to Devise.

Did you do

```
gem install devise
rails generate devise:install
rails generate devise User
rake db:migrate
rails generate devise:views
```

?

The full instructions [can be found here.](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)

Answer (score 1):

You probably forgot to run migrations against your database after you have installed devise. Or there was no such column in the migration.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to have password and passord_confirmation as accessible attributes in your User model like this:

```
attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, etc...
```